# Pyqt5 Two QThread communicate use signal and slot issue

Tags: pyqt, qthread

I'm trying to use the pyqt qthread for multithreading program.

In the code, there are two different workers instance. I try to use signal and slot  for data share.
but it seemed that the signal is blocked until one of the qthread is finished.

this is the code.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication,QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import time
import sys

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):  # A slot takes no params
        for i in range(1, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.intReady.emit(i)

        self.finished.emit()


class Worker2(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):  # A slot takes no params
        for i in range(1, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.intReady.emit(i)

        self.finished.emit()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def revsignal(self, val):
        print("hello rev a signal"+str(val))

def updateLabel(val):
    print("updateLable "+str(val))

app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
# 1 - create Worker and Thread inside the Form
worker = Worker()  # no parent!
thread = QThread()  # no parent!

worker2 = Worker2()
thread2 = QThread()

worker.intReady.connect(updateLabel)
worker.intReady.connect(worker2.revsignal)

worker.moveToThread(thread)
worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
thread.started.connect(worker.work)
# self.thread.finished.connect(app.exit)


worker2.moveToThread(thread2)
worker2.finished.connect(thread2.quit)
thread2.started.connect(worker2.work)

thread2.finished.connect(app.exit)



thread2.start()
print("after thread2 start")
thread.start()
print("after thread1 start.")



sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and the output is here

```
after thread2 start
after thread1 start.
updateLable 1
updateLable 2
updateLable 3
updateLable 4
updateLable 5
updateLable 6
updateLable 7
updateLable 8
updateLable 9
hello rev a signal1
hello rev a signal2
hello rev a signal3
hello rev a signal4
hello rev a signal5
hello rev a signal6
hello rev a signal7
hello rev a signal8
hello rev a signal9

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i don't know why the worker2 thread can't receive the signal as soon as the work1 emit the signal. until the work1 thread ended.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that all slots should be members of a class which inherits from `QObject`. So make a class like this

```
class Manager(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def updateLabel(self, val):
        print("updateLable "+str(val))
manager = Manager()
```

Next, as per the docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads), there is an additional argument which can be passed to `connect` to control the behavior of cross-thread signal processing. You need to change three lines.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt
```

to get the Qt namespace, and both of

```
worker.intReady.connect(manager.updateLabel, type=Qt.DirectConnection)
worker.intReady.connect(worker2.revsignal, type=Qt.DirectConnection)
```

to set the connection type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  It works.   Great.!  

Comment: This just papers over the problem. The actual problem is that the threads sleep during their slots, and thread2 cannot handle worker2.revsignal until worker2.work finally returns.

Comment: Doing things this way will actually break the example, because ***all*** the slots will now be invoked *in the same thread* (i.e. the one that emits the signals). If `revsignal` should be invoked in the second thread, using a direct connection *cannot possibly work* (despite what the OP claims). However, even worse is that `updateLabel` will be invoked *outside the main thread* - so if a QLabel is being updated, thread-safety can no longer be guaranteed (since Qt does not support GUI operations of any kind outside the main thread).

Answer (score 1):

### You're misunderstanding how threads and signals/slots work.

#### Signal and Slot handling

When a signal is emitted, slots that it's connected to should be run. When using a DirectConnection, that means directly calling the slot function, but that's only the default when objects live on the same thread. When objects live on different threads (or you've used a QueuedConnection), the signal enqueues an event to run the slot in the appropriate thread's event queue. This is what you want.

#### Thread event loops

Each thread is a separate thread of executing, running an event loop. The event loop calls the slots that have received a signal, but it does so sequentially, that is, it calls one slot, then when that function returns, it calls the next, and so on.

### What you're doing wrong

It's a combination of 2 things.
First, you're doing your entire logic loop in the slot, meaning no further events will be handled until your loop is finished.
Second, you're calling `time.sleep` in the slot, which causes that entire thread to sleep for 1 second.

Combined, this means that both threads will first call the work slot, be 'busy' for 10 seconds until that slot is done, and then do the rest of the work.

### Solutions

#### Direct Connection

You can use a direct connection, as suggested by [buck54321](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456186/145413), but this just means that the `work` function of `worker1` (running on `thread1`) will call `worker2.revsignal` directly, still on `thread1`.

#### Manually process events

You can call `QCoreApplication.processEvents()` to run (an iteration of) the event loop by hand. Sometimes this can be the right solution, but it's messy,
and you're still going to cause the thread to sleep for a second at a time.

#### Use timed events

Instead of looping, you can use timers to periodically call your slots and do work then. This means you don't have to loop until you're done. I've included an example using `QTimer.singleShot`.

### Code

#### Cleaned up

Here is a cleaned up version that still behaves roughly the same:

```python
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication,QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import time
import sys

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self, number):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = number

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):
        for i in range(1, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.intReady.emit(self.number, i)

        self.finished.emit()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def revsignal(self, val):
        print("hello rev a signal"+str(val))

class Label(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def updateLabel(self, source, val):
        print(f"updateLabel ({source}): {val}")

class Exiter(QObject):
    done = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        super().__init__()
        self.live_threads = num_threads

    @pyqtSlot()
    def finished(self):
        self.live_threads -= 1
        if self.live_threads <= 0:
            self.done.emit()

app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
# 1 - create Worker and Thread inside the Form
worker1 = Worker(1)  # no parent!
thread1 = QThread()  # no parent!

worker2 = Worker(2)
thread2 = QThread()

label = Label()

exiter = Exiter(2) # Waiting for 2 threads

worker1.intReady.connect(label.updateLabel)
worker1.intReady.connect(worker2.revsignal)
worker1.moveToThread(thread1)
worker1.finished.connect(thread1.quit)
thread1.started.connect(worker1.work)
thread1.finished.connect(exiter.finished)

worker2.intReady.connect(label.updateLabel)
worker2.moveToThread(thread2)
worker2.finished.connect(thread2.quit)
thread2.started.connect(worker2.work)
thread2.finished.connect(exiter.finished)

exiter.done.connect(app.exit)


thread2.start()
print("after thread2 start")
thread1.start()
print("after thread1 start.")


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### Hack

This version forces event processing before sleeping, which at least handles other events, but still causes the thread to sleep.

```python
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication,QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import time
import sys

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self, number):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = number

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):
        for i in range(1, 10):
            QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.intReady.emit(self.number, i)

        self.finished.emit()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def revsignal(self, val):
        print("hello rev a signal"+str(val))

class Label(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def updateLabel(self, source, val):
        print(f"updateLabel ({source}): {val}")

class Exiter(QObject):
    done = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        super().__init__()
        self.live_threads = num_threads

    @pyqtSlot()
    def finished(self):
        self.live_threads -= 1
        if self.live_threads <= 0:
            self.done.emit()

app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
# 1 - create Worker and Thread inside the Form
worker1 = Worker(1)  # no parent!
thread1 = QThread()  # no parent!

worker2 = Worker(2)
thread2 = QThread()

label = Label()

exiter = Exiter(2) # Waiting for 2 threads

worker1.intReady.connect(label.updateLabel)
worker1.intReady.connect(worker2.revsignal)
worker1.moveToThread(thread1)
worker1.finished.connect(thread1.quit)
thread1.started.connect(worker1.work)
thread1.finished.connect(exiter.finished)

worker2.intReady.connect(label.updateLabel)
worker2.moveToThread(thread2)
worker2.finished.connect(thread2.quit)
thread2.started.connect(worker2.work)
thread2.finished.connect(exiter.finished)

exiter.done.connect(app.exit)


thread2.start()
print("after thread2 start")
thread1.start()
print("after thread1 start.")


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### Timed events

Here the logic has been rewritten to use a timed event, instead of sleeping.

```python
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QThread, QTimer, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import sys

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self, number):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = number
        self.to_emit = iter(range(1, 10))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):
        try:
            value = next(self.to_emit)
            self.intReady.emit(self.number, value)
            QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.work)
        except StopIteration:
            self.finished.emit()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def revsignal(self, val):
        print("hello rev a signal"+str(val))

class Label(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def updateLabel(self, source, val):
        print(f"updateLabel ({source}): {val}")

class Exiter(QObject):
    done = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        super().__init__()
        self.live_threads = num_threads

    @pyqtSlot()
    def finished(self):
        self.live_threads -= 1
        if self.live_threads <= 0:
            self.done.emit()

app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
# 1 - create Worker and Thread inside the Form
worker1 = Worker(1)  # no parent!
thread1 = QThread()  # no parent!

worker2 = Worker(2)
thread2 = QThread()

label = Label()

exiter = Exiter(2) # Waiting for 2 threads

worker1.intReady.connect(label.updateLabel)
worker1.intReady.connect(worker2.revsignal)
worker1.moveToThread(thread1)
worker1.finished.connect(thread1.quit)
thread1.started.connect(worker1.work)
thread1.finished.connect(exiter.finished)

worker2.intReady.connect(label.updateLabel)
worker2.moveToThread(thread2)
worker2.finished.connect(thread2.quit)
thread2.started.connect(worker2.work)
thread2.finished.connect(exiter.finished)

exiter.done.connect(app.exit)


thread2.start()
print("after thread2 start")
thread1.start()
print("after thread1 start.")


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```